# Compressing floating point that contain parsed decimal numbers

Tags: floating-point, compression, double

I would like to compress a large array of doubles containing a time-series of measurements.

I know that the measurements have been in base-10, but I do not know the precision in advance.

Can I use this fact to improve the compression ratio? [FPC](http://www.csl.cornell.edu/~burtscher/research/FPC/) does not seem to work particularly well on my data set.

Comment: What is “FCP”? There does not seem to be any obvious match with the dozen expansions at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FCP

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Sorry. It should have been FPC. I have added a link.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing that a `double` was parsed from a decimal representation with a given precision indeed provides information: for precision 3, it allows `1.0500000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125`, the `double` nearest to `1.05`, and excludes many nearby `doubles`, which do not have the property of being nearest to any decimal representation with 3 significant digits.

The regularity of such sequences of `double`s seems difficult for a general-purpose compressor to detect: it can only be noticed by looking at consecutive 64-bit slices of data. Even so, no value may ever repeat. Instead, the fact to notice is that all present `double`s are evenly-spaced on intervals of the shape [10<sup>n</sup> … 10<sup>n+1</sup>). It would take a smart general-purpose compressor to notice this and take advantage of it.

You may obtain better compression with traditional string-oriented compression algorithms by expanding the `double`s to their decimal representation, with the number of significant digits applicable at run-time. Since you say that the `double` numbers were obtained from a decimal representation, this transformation should be lossless unless the number of significant decimal digits is more than 15 or so.

This is undoubtedly awkward, and the ideal solution would be if you could use a specialized compression algorithm that would be effective without such costly pre-formating.

Answer (score 1):

For each number, first return zero if it's zero.  Otherwise take the absolute value and divide by ten raised to the floor of the log base ten of the number.  That will give you the mantissa in base ten, a number in [1,10).

Now convert the mantissa to 17 decimal digits.  For `digits` from one to 17, take that many of the decimal digits and convert those back to a double (with a decimal point in the correct place).  Subtract the original mantissa.  When that returns something with absolute value less than 2<sup>-47</sup>, then you stop. `digits` is the number of decimal digits.

Now you can code the decimal mantissa and exponent as integers with, hopefully, less bits than the original double.  You can use a few bits provide the number of bits in the integers.

I don't know how much this will help with your data.  Since you mentioned that this is a time series of measurements, you could also pre-process the data by subtracting successive values after the first one, which might have fewer digits in the differences if the signal is relatively continuous and not changing too rapidly.